# Insufficient permissions for deploying ARM template using Python SDK

Tags: python, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sdk-python

I've got a simple scirpt that should deploy an ARM template:

```py
credentials = ClientSecretCredential(
    client_id="<client-id>",
    client_secret="<client-secret>",
    tenant_id="<tenant-id>"
)

template = requests.get("<template-url>").json()

deployment_properties = {
    'mode': DeploymentMode.incremental,
    'template': template
}

deployment = Deployment(location="eastus", properties=deployment_properties)

client = ResourceManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id="<subscription-id>")
deployment_async_operation = client.deployments.begin_create_or_update_at_subscription_scope("test_deployment", deployment)
deployment_async_operation.wait()
```

When I try to run it, I get this error:

```
Exception Details:  (InsufficientPrivilegesForManagedServiceResource) The requested user doesn't have sufficient privileges to perform the operation.
        Code: InsufficientPrivilegesForManagedServiceResource
        Message: The requested user doesn't have sufficient privileges to perform the operation.
```

The app registration I created, does have user_impersonation permission, which should do the trick.
[image]

Am I missing some permissions here?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error "***Insufficient permissions for deploying ARM template***" usually occurs if you don't have required permissions to perform the deployment.

```py
deployment_async_operation = client.deployments.begin_create_or_update_at_subscription_scope("test_deployment", deployment)
```

From above line of code, I assume you are **deploying the ARM template at subscription level.**
Please check whether you have **permissions** at subscription level of scope.

To perform any action at subscription level you need either **`Global Admin Role`** or **`Owner Role`** for your subscription.

- To know how to assign roles for the subscription, please refer this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal-subscription-admin).

**If still the issue persists**, please check if the below option is enabled or not. If disabled, enable it like below:

***Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> Properties -> Access management for Azure resources***

[image]

Please refer the below **links** for more information:

[User doesn't have permission to create deployment ARM template in Azure - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/250370/user-doesn39t-have-permission-to-create-deployment.html)

[InsufficientPrivilegesForManagedServiceResource · Issue #39 · Azure/Azure-Lighthouse-samples · GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Lighthouse-samples/issues/39)

Comment: Thank you so much! I was wondering what I did wrong, and I did assign the "Contributor" role to the app. Thank you!