# Unable to deploy ARM template with all required Permissions

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-rbac

My requirement is to deploy an arm template using Azure pipelines.

I am referring to this document [Deploying ARM Templates using Azure DevOps Pipelines – Thomas Thornton](https://thomasthornton.cloud/2020/11/17/deploying-arm-templates-using-azure-devops-pipelines/) I don't think I have missed anything.

But I got the below error:

```
Exception Details:  (InsufficientPrivilegesForManagedServiceResource) The requested user doesn't have sufficient privileges to perform the operation.
```

I have enough permissions to perform this but I do not know why I am getting this error

[Api permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6P6K.png)

What permissions am I missing? Any suggestions??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error "***Insufficient permissions for deploying ARM template***" usually occurs if there is any missing required permissions to perform the action.

Please **note** that, if you are deploying the ARM template at subscription level then you have to grant permissions for subscription level scope.

Try assigning the permissions at **subscription level** to resolve the error. You have to be having either **`Global Admin Role`** or **`Owner Role`** for your subscription.

You can **refer** this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal-subscription-admin) to do the same.

You can also enable ***Access management for Azure resources*** as below:

***Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> Properties -> Access management for Azure resources***

[image]

You can **refer** the similar kind of issue solved by me in this [**SO Thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72435820/insufficient-permissions-for-deploying-arm-template-using-python-sdk).